# Timeout a Caliper benchmark

Tags: java, caliper

Is there a way to timeout a caliper benchmark test without an exception? I'd like to simply move on to the next test in the benchmark; skip current test without killing the rest of the tests. I haven't found any documentation of a clear way to do this, so any help is much appreciated. I'm working with an older version of Caliper (0.5).